# Facebook fanpage posts, comments displayed on website

Tags: facebook

im creating website for a small company and i want its fanpage on FB integrated with the site.
I want to have their new posts, comments, etc (everything u get from visiting that fanpage via FB) in iframe or sth like that. I already made my research and i found out u can add a single post (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/) but not whole feed. Is there any other solution than adding this plugin for every post they make on fanpage?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the [Like Box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/) is your best option.

Comment: You have like 2 options which are already answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187419/how-to-embed-a-facebook-pages-feed-into-my-website

Answer (score 0):

You should check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/. They provide you the complete code for the iframe along with the customisation which you want

Comment: You should note the top of the page, where it says, _“Access to the Public Feed API is restricted and usage requires prior approval by Facebook”_ – so I doubt that will be easy to get access to for a small website.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an easier solution, I agree with CBroe that the likebox is your best option.
If you want something more advanced, you can use their [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/) so that you can grab the whole page feed and style it to be part of your page.