# Facebook page plugin does not show preview. Only displays the link

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, embed

I want to embed a facebook post to my html code. So I clicked on the post and chose "Embed Post" and got the below code.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script>(function(d, s, id) {  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script><div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Hi.iCreations/posts/723687861101376" data-width="500"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/Hi.iCreations/posts/723687861101376"><p>Long waited Documentary trailer ReleasedWater is a vital part of almost all life on Earth. We need a safe source of...</p>Posted by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Hi.iCreations/">Icreations</a> on&nbsp;<a href="https://www.facebook.com/Hi.iCreations/posts/723687861101376">Wednesday, March 9, 2016</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

When I paste it in my HTML code, below is how it displays it.

[image]

It is not displayed as a post! There are couple of examples as answers for this question.[How to embed a Facebook page's feed into my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187419/how-to-embed-a-facebook-pages-feed-into-my-website) It says, run the example and when I run it I get the same output. Only the hyperlink is displayed, not the post. Is this some known issue with facebook api? or else is there a workaround? Please advice.

Comment: Are you calling the page you are testing this on using `http://` or  `https://` in your browser? The protocol-relative URL the above code uses to embed the SDK will only work if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm it seems to work at my page.

[image]

I have tested it in my own webpage and it seem to work on every browser. The only thing I can imagine is that you don't have a API installed right, what is a bit strange because its working on my page even when I am not logged in on facebook or anything, or there must be a javascript function that ruins the script from facebook..

I suggest to make your own api, and then go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts. There, you can paste in your post and generate the code. If it is still not working I suggest to paste it in, and than remove every line of code untill it work to see what is distrubing your code.

Comment: I pasted it in a simple html file and still doesn't load. I haven't installed any API! I just copied the code from embed post and pasted it. How do i install the API?

Comment: you should login to https://developers.facebook.com/, from their on you see a dropdown at the top right with "My Apps" and then you have to select "Add a new app"