# Not able to get permission for Facebook API call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our client wants to show the three latests posts from their Facebook wall on their website. Therefore we follow the procedure described here (the second answer) which seems pretty straight forward: [How to embed a Facebook page's feed into my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187419/how-to-embed-a-facebook-pages-feed-into-my-website)

I can generate an access token easily but the call to the following URL fails and gives me the following error message:
https://graph.facebook.com/juwelierwagnervienna/posts?fields=full_picture,picture,link,message,created_time&limit=5&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN

*This endpoint requires the 'manage_pages' or 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature.*

Therefore I requested *manage_pages* and in a separate request *Page Public Content Access* via the App interface. They declined both for the same reason over and over again although I made a pretty detailed description and a video to document my approach including code samples.

*We determined that your app's use case for this permission is invalid, or it's not needed to support its core functionality. You can learn more about the allowed use cases by visiting our Permissions Reference or Features pages. Please resubmit your request, and ensure that you provide a valid use case with notes and screencast clearly explaining: [...]*

I followed all of the instructions and resubmitted the request for approval several times already.

Would love to hear some feedback and recommendations on this one since I'm at a dead end here and the Facebook Support Chat can not help me either.

Comment: You don’t need _both_, the message said _or_ for a reason. Your client wants to show posts from their own page, so this is not “public access” - you want `manage_pages`, and that’s it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I made separate permission requests for manage_pages and Page Public Content Access - both got declined for the same reason.

Comment: Don’t see why they should decline `manage_pages`, but I guess it depends on how exactly you explained your use case.